# numerical analysis - ODE exercise

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-calculus

I'm trying to solve this exercise, however to be quite frank, I don't really have any idea on where to begin and proceed from there. It goes as follows:

Let $f$ be a real periodic function, $f: [0,2\pi] \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(0) = f(2\pi)$. Let $\gamma,\beta \in \mathbb{R}$ with $\beta \neq 0$. The following ODE is given:

$$(1): \frac{d^2u}{dt^2}(t)+\beta\frac{du}{dt}(t)+\gamma^2u(t) = f(t)$$

(a): Assume that $f(t) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_k$sin$(kt)$ , and let $(u_k)_{k=1}^\infty$ denote solutions of $$(2): \frac{d^2u_k}{dt^2}(t)+\beta\frac{du_k}{dt}(t)+\gamma^2u_k(t) = \sin(kt) , \qquad k = 1,2,3\dots$$

Using the fact that $u_k(t) = A_k(t)\cos(kt) + B_k\sin(kt), \quad A_k,B_k \in \mathbb{R}$, solve the ODE $(2)$ for every $k$ by finding $A_k, B_k$ and consequently, $u_k(t)$

(b): By superposition (linearity) we then have $u(t) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty a_ku_k(t)$ is the solution to $(1)$. Write the complete solution $u(t)$

(c): Find $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$ \max_{0\leq j\leq1000}\lvert (f_1^N-f)(\frac{j}{1000}2\pi)\rvert \lt \varepsilon$$
for $\epsilon= 10^{-\ell} , \ell \in \{1,2,3\}$ and

$f(t) =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $0\lt t \lt \pi$,} \\
0, & \text{if $t \in \{0,\pi,2\pi\}$}\\
-1, & \text{if $\pi \lt t \lt 2\pi$}
\end{cases}$

Now I even struggle to come up with anything really. How would I start solving an exercise like this?

Comment: The first part is the standard solurion of a second order inhomogeneous  DE. In the third part I guess that $f_1^N$ refers to the N'th partial sum in (b), but what does the subscript 1 indicate?

Comment: @Paul I don't really know as I have not yet covered differential equations and still somehow this exercise came up. Every exercise I've found covers different examples. As for the subscript, there were some additional exercises that I did not post here. They mostly involved plotting some graphes. How does one start solving this exercise? Apologies for my lack of knowledge!

Comment: For (a) substitute in $u_k(t)$ on the left in (2) then equate $sin(kt)$ and $cos(kt)$ terms to give 2 simultaneous equations for $A_k$ and $B_k$, which you can find in terms of $\beta$, $\gamma$ and $k$. Is (c) a programming task?

Comment: @Paul Okay I'll give it a shot. That's also what I thought what I had to do. But I was not quite sure which way around. So I substitute $(1)$ for $\sin(kt)$ in $(2)$?. I think it is supposed to be a programming task.

Comment: Sorry, been away. You sub in $u_k$ on the left, differentiate then gather the $sin(kt)$ and $cos(kt)$ terms together. These terms are linearly independent so that if, for example, you have $asin(kx)+bcos(kx) = 0$ for all x then both a and b must be 0. This idea will give you two equations for $A_k$ and $B_k$.